# Can I use for loop to create class?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

I create swipe app for swipe Page1(), Page2() in main.dart which class Page1(), Page2() show in pages.dart. All code I use from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfDOHxu1xCc) ([github](https://github.com/ufrshubham/Flutter-Basics/tree/master/PageView%20-%20Navigation%20using%20PageController/lib)).

I want to create 30 pages. Can I use for loop to create 30 class ?

main.dart

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _seletedItem = 0;
  var _pages = [Page1(), Page2()];
  var _pageController = PageController();
```

pages.dart

```
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('First Page', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),),),);
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('Second Page',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),),),);
  }
}
```

Comment: are your all pages the same? i mean they have the same widgets and only differ in data they show?

Comment: yes, same widgets and only differ in data

Comment: so use one generic `class Page extends StatelessWidget { ...` and pass your data in `Page` widget constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this example here i am passing index as param to page but you can pass your custom data from your custom list too.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _seletedItem = 0;
  var _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page Controller looop - Demo'),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        children: List<Widget>.generate(1000,(i) => Page(i:i);,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _seletedItem = index;
          });
        },
        controller: _pageController,
      ),
     
    );
  }
}


class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final i;

  const Page({Key key, this.i}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          '$i Page',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```